# How to translate dynamic text from english to spanish in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to translate text (string and date both) from English language to Spanish language in C#.
The text ill get will be dynamic so it can be anything. 
Can anyone please suggest as to how this can be done.

Also i don't want restrictions regarding number of characters like google API does.

Comment: Find another API. Given this question, I would recommend against building your own translation system.

Comment: [ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/quickstarts/csharp ] might help

Comment: Don't listen to @Lucifer, he's trying to tempt you down the path of evil.

Comment: @john why is that path of evil :D

Comment: Your name is Lucifer :)

Comment: Thanks @Aphelion for the suggestion. but i just want to translate dynamically rather then making up own system. Certainly somebody would have tried doing it this way sometime.

Comment: @user Unfortunately recommendations for software, etc. are off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: @Aphelion I don't have issues with API. Just the character restriction might create complexity for me. May be the limit of characters allowed is more then it will work for me.

Comment: Thanks @Lucifer, I am looking into your suggestion.